# While writing fibonacci series in python, getting IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
def fib(n):
    lst = [0,1]
    for i in range(n):
        lst.append(lst[n] + lst[n+1])
    print lst

fib(3)
```

Getting `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong index in `lst.append(lst[n] + lst[n+1])`. You should be using: `lst.append(lst[i] + lst[i+1])` (`i` not `n`).

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong index `n`, you should use `i`.

You can fix like this,

```
def fib(n):
    lst = []
    for item in range(n):
        lst.append(item + item+1)
    print lst

fib(3)
```